# Git : post-receive hook not fired after a local fetch on a remote bare repo

Tags: git, github, git-bare

Here the context:

- Local development on my computer
- Source code pushed on Github
- Remote server deployment with a bare repo
- post-receive hook set on the bare repo to deploy on the Apache directory
- New content deployment via SSH  -> git remote add live ssh://user@server/path/to/deploy.git then git push live master

Content of the post-receive hook in the remote bare repo:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html git checkout -f
```

Everything works fine remotely, but I'd like to be able to **deploy directly from the bare repo on the remote server**. The next step will be a script called thru https to be able to deploy in case of SSH is unavailable.

Push on my local computer:

> git push origin master:master To https://github.com/Myself/repo.git
> d8856273..**e3fe4b4c**  master -> master

On the bare repositery, before fetching

> ~/deploy.git$ git rev-parse --short HEAD
>
> d885627

Fetching locally from remote server:

> ~/deploy.git$ git fetch https://github.com/Myself/repo.git master:master
>
> From https://github.com/Myself/repo
>
> d885627..**e3fe4b4**   master -> master

The new content is there. However, /var/www/html remains unchanged.

It seems that post-receive hook is not fired after fetching. How can I sort this out?

Comment: The `post-receive` hook runs on a remote repository. `git fetch` doesn't invoke it. When you run `git push` from A to B successfully, the `post-receive` hook in B will be invoked.

Comment: @ElpieKay thanks for the confirmation. I guess the easiest way is to invoke "GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/www-data/valentine git checkout -f" locally after the content has been fetched